# BeanDefinitionStoreException during start jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

This is my maven package catalog:

- forum

  - forum-common
  - forum-mbg
  - forum-protal(with main class here)
  - forum-security

When I trying to run the jar file which is generated after packaging my project, I got an exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [xyz.aiinirii.forum.portal.config.PortalForumSecurity
Config]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unresolvable class definition for class [xyz.aiinirii.forum.portal.config.PortalForumSecurityConfig]            
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:609) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE] 
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:310) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.
2.8.RELEASE]                                                                                                                                                                     
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.
8.RELEASE]                                                                                                                                                                       
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]          
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:303) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.
2.8.RELEASE]                                                                                                                                                                     
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.
8.RELEASE]                                                                                                                                                                       
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:206) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]          
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:174) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]          
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.R
ELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]                                                                                                                                                      
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.
2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]                                                                                                                                                 
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280) ~[spring-
context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]                                                                                                                                       
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.2.
8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]                                                                                                                                                   
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar
!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]                                                                                                                                                                
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]       
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/
:2.3.3.RELEASE]                                                                                                                                                                  
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]                                       
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]                                       
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]                                
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]                                           
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]                                          
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]                                          
        at xyz.aiinirii.forum.portal.ForumPortalApplication.main(ForumPortalApplication.java:15) ~[classes!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]                                                     
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]                                                                               
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]                                                             
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]                                                     
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]                                                                                                   
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[forum-portal-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]                                      
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109) ~[forum-portal-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]                                                  
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[forum-portal-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]                                                   
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[forum-portal-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]                                               
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unresolvable class definition for class [xyz.aiinirii.forum.portal.config.PortalForumSecurityConfig]                              
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:331) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]                                            
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecuritySelector.selectImports(GlobalMethodSecuritySelector.java:51) ~[spring-security
-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.4.RELEASE]                                                                                                                                       
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:580) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE] 
        ... 29 common frames omitted                                                                                                                                             
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xyz/aiinirii/forum/security/config/SecurityConfig                                                                                     
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]                                                                                                  
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[na:na]                                                                                           
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151) ~[na:na]                                                                            
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:514) ~[na:na]                                                                                       
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:422) ~[na:na]                                                                                             
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:416) ~[na:na]                                                                                             
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691) ~[na:na]                                                                             
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:415) ~[na:na]                                                                                         
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[na:na]                                                                                              
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[forum-portal-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]                   
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]                                                                                              
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]                                                                                                            
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:427) ~[na:na]                                                                                                            
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]                                                     
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:324) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]                                            
        ... 31 common frames omitted                                                                                                                                             
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xyz.aiinirii.forum.security.config.SecurityConfig                                                                                   
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435) ~[na:na]                                                                                         
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[na:na]                                                                                              
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[forum-portal-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]                   
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]                                                                                              
        ... 46 common frames omitted
```

However, when I run the application on IDEA, it succeeded.

Here is my `xyz.aiinirii.forum.portal.config.PortalForumSecurityConfig` class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class PortalForumSecurityConfig extends SecurityConfig {

    private UmsMemberService memberService;

    @Autowired
    public void setMemberService(UmsMemberService memberService) {
        this.memberService = memberService;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> memberService.loadUserByUsername(username);
    }

}
```

and forum/pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>xyz.aiinirii</groupId>
    <artifactId>forum</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>forum</name>
    <description>Backend of a forum system</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>forum-common</module>
        <module>forum-portal</module>
        <module>forum-mbg</module>
        <module>forum-security</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <start-class>xyz.aiinirii.forum.portal.ForumPortalApplication</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jjwt.version>0.9.0</jjwt.version>
        <pagehelper-starter.version>1.2.10</pagehelper-starter.version>
        <pagehelper.version>5.1.8</pagehelper.version>
        <swagger2.version>2.9.2</swagger2.version>
        <swagger-models.version>1.6.0</swagger-models.version>
        <swagger-annotations.version>1.6.0</swagger-annotations.version>
        <mybatis.version>2.1.3</mybatis.version>
        <mysql-connect.version>8.0.21</mysql-connect.version>
        <mybatis-generator.version>1.3.7</mybatis-generator.version>
        <forum-common.version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</forum-common.version>
        <forum-mbg.version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</forum-mbg.version>
        <forum-security.version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</forum-security.version>
        <hutool.version>4.6.3</hutool.version>
        <validation-api.version>2.0.1.Final</validation-api.version>
        <druid.version>1.1.22</druid.version>
        <jaxb.version>2.3.0</jaxb.version>
        <activation.version>1.1.1</activation.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cn.hutool</groupId>
            <artifactId>hutool-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>${mybatis.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>cn.hutool</groupId>
                <artifactId>hutool-all</artifactId>
                <version>${hutool.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger2.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger2.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger-models.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger-annotations.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.pagehelper</groupId>
                <artifactId>pagehelper-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>${pagehelper-starter.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.pagehelper</groupId>
                <artifactId>pagehelper</artifactId>
                <version>${pagehelper.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
                <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>${mysql-connect.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
                <artifactId>mybatis-generator-core</artifactId>
                <version>${mybatis-generator.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>xyz.aiinirii</groupId>
                <artifactId>forum-common</artifactId>
                <version>${forum-common.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xyz.aiinirii</groupId>
                <artifactId>forum-mbg</artifactId>
                <version>${forum-mbg.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xyz.aiinirii</groupId>
                <artifactId>forum-security</artifactId>
                <version>${forum-security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>${validation-api.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
                <artifactId>druid-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>${druid.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
                <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                <version>${activation.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And forum-portal/pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>forum-portal</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>forum-portal</name>
    <description>forum-portal project for forum</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>xyz.aiinirii</groupId>
        <artifactId>forum</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xyz.aiinirii</groupId>
            <artifactId>forum-mbg</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xyz.aiinirii</groupId>
            <artifactId>forum-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: Remove the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` from the parent and only add it to the project that needs to be a Spring Boot project. Which is probably only the `forum-portal` project not the other projects.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you! The problem is solved!